# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, C:\Neo4jCommunity

Tags: eclipse, neo4j, graph-databases

I'm facing a problem which blocks me. I work on a project with Neo4j Database Graphs.
    My problem is when i run java application, it displays me in console :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, C:\Neo4jCommunity
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:358)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:90)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:199)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:70)
    at HelloWorld.createDataBase(HelloWorld.java:35)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:28)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions@1304421' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:489)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:72)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:106)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:335)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/store/Directory
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.DirectoryFactory.<clinit>(DirectoryFactory.java:53)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneKernelExtensions.directoryFactory(LuceneKernelExtensions.java:36)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneLabelScanStoreExtension.newKernelExtension(LuceneLabelScanStoreExtension.java:71)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneLabelScanStoreExtension.newKernelExtension(LuceneLabelScanStoreExtension.java:39)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions.init(KernelExtensions.java:104)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:483)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.store.Directory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 15 more


I don't know where the problem comes from, knowing that I install all NEO4j jars needed.

    enter code here

Thank you all
```